# url to fetch with parameter for django view

Tags: javascript, django, url, fetch

I'm facing a problem with my javascript code when trying to use AJAX instead of href link.

I need to hit a django url that looks like this (Django 2.2):

```
path('one-time/<str:product_url>/', OneTimeProductView.as_view(), name='one_time_product')
```

the origial code in the django template was:

```
<a href="{% url 'one_time_product' product %}">{{product}}</a>
```

I now want to use ajax call to make the whole process opened inside of a modal. In my javascript code my fetch function looks like this:

```
   function handleAccess(){
    var url = "{%  url 'one_time_product' product %}" ;
    fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}',
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
        .then (response => {
            response.json();
        })
        .then (data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
};
```

I know i'm missing something related to the params in the url variable but I just don't know how to add it properly so that i fit the url path.

This is the error that I get when I hit the button

> NoReverseMatch at /one-time/ Reverse for 'one_time_product' with no
> arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['one\-time\/(?P<product_url>[^/]+)\/$']

How should I write the url in the fetch function ?

I will appreciate and anyone can point me into the right direction here.

Thanks

Comment: Who calls the handleAccess? Is there an onclick on the original link element?

Answer (score 1):

It was a tricky one.
I solved it with the back-end dev.

```
var url = "{%  url 'one_time_product' product_url=0 %}".replace('0', {{ product }}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a named parameter in the URL definition (product_url).

On top of my head, you should use the url templatetag like this:

```
var url = "{%  url 'one_time_product' product_url=product.url %}" ;
```

Change the `product.url` to the actual url (or slug) from your product model.

Comment: not sure how the actual url is formatted.
From the view file this is what is expected:

    def get(self, request, product_url=None):
        site = get_current_site(request)

        if product_url:
            context = {}
            pro_access = "Anonymous"
            try :